# How does ads actually make you money when you upload a Game?

Tags: advertisements

I am an independent game developer and I have made my own game. I want to upload it on the Play store and I understand that you need to pay $25. But there's something I don't understand in terms earning money. I have look on websites and some websites say for every 1000 views on an ad, you get $0.10 but on another, it says every view you get $0.10.

I don't understand the system of earning money when it comes to putting ads in your game. I understand its a bit of a stupid question but it will help when i upload my game for real.

Answer (score 6):

Ad networks will generally pay you for one or both of

- ad views, where you load the ad and display it to a user
- ad clicks, where you do the above and then a user *actually clicks on* the ad

The actual rates of payment will depend on the specific ad provider and in some cases the deal you negotiate with that provider, but that's the gist of it. Clicks generally pay more than views, since they're more useful to whoever paid to put the ad on their network. But they also happen less often.

Generally you will only get a payout when you are owed above a certain threshold of money; they won't cut you a check for $0.20, for example, but will rather pay you by the Xth of the month when your account balance exceeds $Y (or similar).

Typically you are prohibited from doing "shady" things like displaying the ads too quickly, or loading the ads but hiding them, or other sorts of deceptive practices.

Consult the specific terms of your agreement with whatever providers you are choosing or evaluating for details.

Comment: Ninja answer! You type very fast :P

Comment: @Josh Petrie  Thank you very much, you've made it clear :D